# How can I use Autodesk Forge Viewer API for my web application?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I want to use Autodesk forge for my web application that allows my clients to save their model files and view them online. However, the problem I am facing is that the viewer is not unique for the clients as it runs on a client secret key. So, once I upload any model in the forge viewer, it appears to all the clients who are using it. So, how can I make sure that I only get the viewer that just opens the models that are present in the project of the client? Is there any way by which I won't have to use the access key so that the models do no get saved up alongside the viewer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement **user authentication** and keep their files separate (e.g. separate buckets named ) - or at least know who should have access to what.

Authentication could be based on an **Autodesk account** as well if you wanted. Anyone can have such a thing for free.

I hope you are keeping the **client secret** on the server so the clients don't have access to it and only pass to the client an **access token** with scope **viewables:read** only - that could not be used e.g. to list the contents of buckets - see e.g. https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels